# view background

Tags: iphone, background

I have a little problem, I have a view with a UIScrollView, I've imposted a background image on my view with

```
 self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
```

on simulator is all ok, the image are fixed while I scroll down but on my device the image was repeat while I scroll down.
There is a way for fixed the image on my device?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you're are getting a memory alert while running on the device (put a break point). Also you can invoke a memory alert in the simulator and see if something odd happends.

Comment: Now I try, but one thing, i forgot to say a thing, I use sdk 4.1 but my device is only an itouch 1g with firmware 3.1.3 can be the problem?